# How to do If else within <xsl:next-iteration> <xsl:with-param

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to do an If condition within an xsl:with-param within an xsl:next-iteration.

My xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XmlRoot>
   <Rec>
      <pD>20181221</pD>
      <gl>00001</gl>
      <le_Ac>29246</le_Ac>
      <eid>009158099</eid>
      <tA>9.61</tA>
   </Rec>
   <Rec>
      <pD>20181221</pD>
      <gl>00001</gl>
      <le_Ac>29246</le_Ac>
      <eid>009158099</eid>
      <tA>10.61</tA>
   </Rec>   
   <Rec>
      <pD>20181221</pD>
      <gl>00001</gl>
      <le_Ac>60300</le_Ac>
      <eid>909154343</eid>
      <tA>11.61</tA>
   </Rec>   
   <Rec>
      <pD>20181221</pD>
      <gl>00001</gl>
      <le_Ac>60300</le_Ac>
      <eid>909154343</eid>
      <tA>12.61</tA>
   </Rec>
</XmlRoot>
```

And my xslt is as below, I'm trying to stream a really large xml.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:iterate select="XmlRoot/Rec">
            <xsl:param name="mapAllKeys" as="map(xs:string, xs:float?)" select="map{}"/>
            <xsl:param name="map29246" as="map(xs:string, xs:float?)" select="map{}"/>
            <xsl:param name="mapDummy" as="map(xs:string, xs:float?)" select="map{}"/>
            <xsl:on-completion>
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="map:keys($mapAllKeys)!(. || concat('&quot;',',','&quot;') || $mapAllKeys(.))" separator="&#10;"/>-->
                    <xsl:for-each 
                        select="map:for-each($mapAllKeys,function ($k, $v){$k})">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="if(map:contains($map29246,.)) then map:get($map29246,.) else 0"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:on-completion>
            <xsl:variable name="current-entry" select="copy-of()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="pDt">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$current-entry/pD = ''"><xsl:value-of select="$current-entry/aD"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$current-entry/pD"/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="key" select="$current-entry/concat(pD, eid, gl,na)"/>
            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="mapAllKeys"
                    select="
                    if (map:contains($mapAllKeys, xs:string($key))) then
                        map:put($mapAllKeys, xs:string($key), map:get($mapAllKeys, xs:float(1.0)))
                    else
                        map:put($mapAllKeys, xs:string($key), xs:float(1.0))"
                />

                <xsl:with-param name="map29246"
                    select="
                    if($current-entry/le_Ac = '29246') then
                       if (map:contains($map29246, xs:string($key))) then
                          map:put($map29246, xs:string($key), map:get($map29246, xs:string($key)) + xs:float($current-entry/tA))
                       else
                          map:put($map29246, xs:string($key), xs:float($current-entry/tA))
                    else
                    map:put($mapDummy, 'DUMMY', xs:float('0.0'))
                    "/>

            </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main problem is the code 
if($current-entry/le_Ac = '29246') then
never satisfies.

I want to add to the map only when the le_Ac = 29246

Also, it always asks for an else part, anyway to avoid the else part?
I'm trying to use a dummy map to bypass it.

any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you reduce the code samples to a complete minimum to allow us to reproduce the problem, showing the result you want and the one you get? I am trying to understand what you want to achieve there but it seems there is code in there like the declaration  of the variable `pDt` that is not even used. As for the last question about not adding anything to the map, I think in the last `else` instead of `map:put($mapDummy, 'DUMMY', xs:float('0.0'))` I would expect `else $map29246`. Not sure however I have grasped what you want to achieve and what the dummy map is then used for.

Comment: `" instead of map:put($mapDummy, 'DUMMY', xs:float('0.0'))` I would expect `else $map29246"`   - Perfect, this is what I was looking for! thanks a lot!

Comment: I have included the suggestion of the previous comment into the answer, if the problem is solved you can accept the answer so that your question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the question about not adding anything to the map, I think in the last `else` instead of `map:put($mapDummy, 'DUMMY', xs:float('0.0'))` I would expect `else $map29246`.

As you also tagged the question as [xslt-grouping](/questions/tagged/xslt-grouping), it might be that the whole problem could be solved with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="XmlRoot/Rec!map:merge(*!map { local-name() : string() })" composite="yes" group-by="?pD, ?eid, ?gl, ?na">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(current-grouping-key()), sum(current-group()[?le_Ac = '29246']?tA!xs:decimal(.))" separator="&#10;"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Output for your sample with Saxon 9.8.0.12 EE in oXygen is

```
2018122100915809900001
20.22
2018122190915434300001
0
```

Another approach would be

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="XmlRoot/Rec!copy-of()" composite="yes" group-by="pD, eid, gl,na">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(current-grouping-key()), sum(current-group()[le_Ac = 29246]/tA)" separator="&#10;"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't made any measurements with large inputs to see which one performs better or at least uses less memory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try the other two methods and see how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm using Saxon EE 9.7.0.12, and for the two sample code you've giveb I get the warning `Requested initial mode  is streamable, but the supplied input is not streamed` is this because of the lower version?

Comment: How do you run Saxon EE 9.7, is that inside oXygen? For oXygen in the Saxon processor specific options of your transformation scenario you have to explicitly enable streamed processing, not sure whether they have that supported for 9.7 however.

Comment: See the item "Enable streaming mode" in https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/advanced-saxon-xslt-options.html.

Comment: I ran this in both Oxygen and Workday Studio. Studio uses v9.7.0.12, I tested this in Oxygen using v9.7.0.19 and I get this warning in both Workday studio and Oxygen. However, when I use v9.8.0.5 in Oxygen, your code works.  So, looks like a limitation of the lower version, bummer!

Comment: Saxon 9.8 is the first release to implement the XSLT 3.0 W3C recommendation published in 2017 so you should try to at least use that version. Although I don't understand why your attempt with streaming would work without a warning while another approach also using `xsl:mode streamable="yes"` doesn't. But in the case of oXygen I would ask their support, either in their dedicated forum or by email, they are very knowledgeable about restrictions of their integration of Saxon into their IDE.

Comment: Hi Martin, 9.7 is the version on the Workday server, so I have to use that. Also, 9.7 is the first version to support streaming.

Comment: I can't help with something I don't know, like Workday server. If the environment restricts you to a particular processor and version then tag your question appropriately, hopefully someone with expertise in that area then can help out. It is still not clear to me whether you get that warning "Requested initial mode is streamable, but the supplied input is not streamed" with any attempt to use streaming in your environment or only with some particular code. If you get it with any streaming attempt then I guess, while having 9.7, they don't use its API appropriately to use streaming.

Comment: Not sure whether 9.7 is supposed to have http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/javadoc/com/saxonica/config/StreamingTransformerFactory.html, I think that was introduced because the oXygen guys use JAXP instead of s9api and with the existing JAXP they had a similar or the same warning issue, so to continue to allow them to use JAXP but if needed set it up for streaming Saxonica created StreamingTransformerFactory.